# Long lists of possible errors marked as duplicate of poorly-written question

Tags: discussion

I encountered this today: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

I found it as I reviewed for reopening an admittedly poor question: [can't upload image in PHP to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857464/cant-upload-image-in-php-to-mysql)

This question was marked as a duplicate of the list-of-erorrs reference question as well as another question explaining how to log errors, presumably because the poster had not included the actual error message in their post.

I know I'm not the biggest SO user but I don't see how that is:

- Useful
- Not douchy

I find two problems here, the first is just with regards to the particular closed question.  Closing it as a duplicate of a question describing how to log errors is not accurate, as that is not what it is asking.  If the poster needs to include an error message, preferably tell them that, or at least close it in another way.  ESPECIALLY if the poster is a new SO user.

My second issue: is a programming novice really supposed to look through this, find their error, go the 'answer' explaining that error, and then attempt to understand the general cases where that error happens well enough to apply them to their particular solution?

Why is this a list of "answers" instead of individual questions that could themselves be marked as duplicates?

What actually *should* have happened here?

Comment: First of all, is the question answerable as of current writing? Are the dupes considered helpful? If it's not answerable without guessing much, and the current dupes are considered helpful (my guts say yes), then I think it's justified, since otherwise the question would be closed as a more vague "unclear" or "debugging problem", so there's no different on the result.

Comment: You'll have to focus on cause and effect to get somewhere.  The cause was a "it doesn't work" question, the effect was links to posts that show how to add the required error checking and how to interpret those errors.  You want a different kind of effect, tell us what should have happened.

Comment: @braiam The linked duplicate has no mention to the problem mentioned in this question, so it implies that closing unclear as duplicate is wrong - correct?

Comment: @user202729 it asks what to do with unclear question. This question asks what should have happened with an unclear question. If you remove the time sensitive from the later to ask "what should happen", both questions ask the same thing.

Comment: Ok it's a little ridiculous this question suffered the same fate, being closed as duplicate of something more general that doesn't answer the specific issue.  But anyways... what *is the answer*?  The linked question doesn't actually mention closing as duplicate at all.  Does that mean that the original post in question shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

Close it the *other way* would be *unclear what you're asking* or *No MCVE*. Because I don't see how useful it will be to answer that question given the lack of details about errors or debug info. No future visitor will benefit from it as they will not find that particular question in their search. At best they stumble upon it.

The question you linked to is incomplete and don't include any errors that code produces or an debug attempt.

Of course is closing and linking to a carefully curated and maintained canonical the right action. It is extremely helpful for that specific user that seem to be new to that language (and SO). It is a win-win.

Comment: How is it helpful?  The user just sees that someone closed their question as a duplicate of something that it is not a duplicate of, and is confused.  At best, if they understand the "hint" the closer is giving, it is passive-aggressive.  I think it would be a lot better to link to the 'How to Ask' page, either manually or by one of the closing types that automatically adds that link to the question.

Comment: We can't solve their confusion. They have been handed the info they need to work out the problem on their own. Moderating a post is not passive-aggressive. If they want help no matter what they should visit a forum.

Comment: Remember, duplicates are not only useful for the asker, but for the future readers. In what way someone that has the same vague question would find that monstrosity helpful?

Comment: @Braiam I don't judge the quality of that PHP canonical because I can't and won't. If you ask me that whole PHP should be blacklisted but I'm only a by-stander and I'm sure the PHP tag followers have enough knowledge around to make that judgement call and/or come up with something that better suits these kind of needs. I'm only answering the meta question.

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the quality of php question, because... it's not a question. It's a list.

Comment: @Braiam Of course if they have the same vague question, they need to log errors to find out their exact cause, because the cause is *almost surely* different.

Comment: @Dave Would leaving a comment saying "Your question is too vague. You need to give more information, first turn on logging and see if there is any error message. See more details at <...>" useful?

Comment: @user202729 then close it as unclear. Duplicate implies that the answer to that question is in the other question, but if you can't even answer the question you are closing, how can you say what the answer is?

Comment: @user202729 that doesn't need voting to close.

Comment: @Braiam Uh, my point is, your suggestion (VTC as unclear and leave no comment, if I understood correctly) is less useful than the current way (VTC as duplicate).

Comment: @user202729 useful in what sense? An vague question linking to a list isn't in my book. If you want to help the OP to make their question answerable, just comment what the question lacks. Voting to close an unclear question is what should be done in any case.

Comment: @Braiam So tl;dr you think that it's better to VTC as unclear and comment with a link to the "how to debug" question instead of VTC as duplicate. Post it (as an alternative answer?) and see how the community votes.

Comment: @user202729 no, I don't think it's better. It's The Right Thing™ to do. That's what the help center says we should use comments and close votes for. Also, that answer wouldn't answer this question.